# How to add a child element to the top of StackPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I'm trying to add some child elements of StackPanel on top.

There is a code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
  <Border Background="SkyBlue">
    <TextBlock>Stacked Item #1</TextBlock>
  </Border>
  <Border Background="CadetBlue">
    <TextBlock>Stacked Item #2</TextBlock>
  </Border>
  <Border Background="LightGoldenRodYellow">
    <TextBlock >Stacked Item #3</TextBlock>
  </Border>
```

and there is a image:

[image]

I want the child elements to be added up instead of down, how can I do this?

**Like this**:
Stacked Item 3
Stacked Item 2
Stacked Item 1

Comment: Reverse the order of the items in your XAML?

Comment: @canton7, yes, i need dat

Comment: That's your answer, then? Edit your XAML, and put those `Borders` in the reverse order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
StackPanel.Children.Insert(0, UIElement)
```

This will insert child element at the head of the list.